# Undefined behavior with pointer arithmetic on dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c99, pointer-arithmetic

I'm probably misunderstanding this, but does the c99 spec prevent any form of pointer arithmetic on dynamically allocated memory?

From 6.5.6p7...

> For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type.

... a pointer to an object not in an array is treated as if it points into an array of 1 item (when using the operators + and -). Then in this snippet:

```
char *make_array (void) {
    char *p = malloc(2*sizeof(*p));
    p[0] = 1; // valid
    p[1] = 2; // invalid ?
    return p;
}
```

...the second subscript `p[1]` is invalid? Since `p` points to an object not in an array it is treated as pointing to an object in an array of one item and then from 6.5.6p8...

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression. In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i+n-th and i−n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if the expression P points to the last element of an array object, the expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object, and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array object. If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined. If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is evaluated.

...we have undefined behaviour since we dereference past the array bound (the one implied to have length 1).

Edit:

OK, to try to clarify more what confuses me, let's do it step-by-step:

1.) `p[1]` is defined to mean `*(p+1)`.
2.) `p` points to an object that isn't inside of an array, so it's treated as if it points to an object inside an array of length 1 for the purpose of evalutating `p+1`.
3.) `p+1` produces a pointer 1 past the array that p is implied to point into.
4.)  `*(p+1)` does the invalid dereference.

Comment: "since we dereference past the array bound", yet `p` is not an _array_.

Comment: I know it's not; I stated it in the question. But is there an implied array here whose bounds is being crossed? It says p is treated as if it points to an object in an array.

Comment: Note that in 7.22.3.4p2 `The malloc function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size and whose value is indeterminate.`. The allocated space is treated as one object. You then take the object pointer and cast it implicitly to `char *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From *C99, 7.20.3 - Memory management functions* (emphasis mine) :

> The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object and then used to access such an object **or an array of such objects** in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated).

This implies that the allocated memory can be accessed as an array of `char` (as per your example), and so pointer arithmetic is well defined.

Comment: Honestly, I'm more confused by that paragraph than anything. What does "access array of such objects" even mean? The `[]` operator is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic which means (per my original post) that I'm doing arithmetic on a pointer that is implied to point to an object in an array of length 1...

Comment: @zagortenay333 : that quote says that the result of `malloc` can be assigned to any pointer type (eg. `char*`), and that that pointer can then be used to access the allocated memory as an array of that type (eg. array of `char`), within the bounds of the allocated memory. Since pointer arithmetic is well defined on an array of `char` as per your quotes, all is well.

Comment: Hmm. So 7.20.3 is basically correcting this? I.e., would I be right that the above is UB if 7.20.3 didn't include the "array of such object" part?

Comment: @zagortenay333 `malloc` returns one object, and this object is treated as array of length `1`. What you assumed is that `malloc` returns many objects where each one is treated as array of length `1`, which is a false assumption.

Comment: @Osiris : sure, `malloc` returns one object, but this object can be used as an array object (the alignment requirements allow it to be used as any type of object) of any size (not just 1), as long as the size of the array fits in the allocated memory.

Comment: @zagortenay333 : I can't immediately find another quote that says the same thing - that's not to say there isn't one. I wouldn't use the word "correcting" though - allowing dynamically allocated memory to be used for arrays is a pretty fundamental feature, so it's normal that `malloc` is defined such that that's allowed.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Would you mind looking at the edit I appended just to make sure we are on the same wavelength and I'm not missing something. It seems to me that unless you give an explicit "correction" then I'm right that this is UB.

Comment: @zagortenay333 : I understand your confusion, but it's due to a faulty assumption. You assume that "`p` points to an object that isn't inside of an array", but it is. That's what the quote in my answer allows : it allows the memory that gets allocated by `malloc` to be (used as) an array object (in your example an array of 2 `char`s). So both `p[0]` and `p[1]` can be accessed.

Comment: @zagortenay333 `malloc` in C kinda gives you memory containing all possible objects and arrays thereof. But, even though e.g. an `int` and `float` objects "exist" at the same time at the same memory location, accessing them through an lvalue of non-compatible type is not a violation of strict aliasing rules because they are formulated in terms of effective type and freshly allocated memory does not have an effective type. Sounds like a complete mess, but this is how the Committee managed to reconcile dynamic memory with string aliasing rules.